# Local User LaunchAgent via SSH: Operation not permitted

Tags: ssh, launchd

I have a launch agent on a remote machine which runs Yosemite. The LaunchAgent is saved to `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` and I am the owner:

```
$ ls -l ~/Library/LaunchAgents
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff  803 Jan 13 15:13 org.my.custom.plist
$ ls -l@ ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.my.custom.plist
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff  803 Jan 13 15:13 /Users/me/Library/LaunchAgents/org.my.custom.plist
    com.apple.TextEncoding   15
```

When logging in via SSH (as that particular user), attempting to load the file produces the following exchange:

```
$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.my.custom.plist
/Users/me/Library/LaunchAgents/org.my.custom.plist: Operation not permitted
```

Why is the operation not permitted when I'm the owner? It works fine under Sierra.

Comment: Do you run ssh or launchctl on the remote host inside tmux?

Comment: @klanomath No, just run it straight

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be an issue with the launchctl 'session' that is used for the agent and that is incorrectly inferred by the `start` command. The new version of launchctl has some new commands for loading agents that allow you to specify this, see [here](https://babodee.wordpress.com/2016/04/09/launchctl-2-0-syntax/).

The following seems to work via SSH:

```
launchctl bootstrap gui/<UID> /Users/me/Library/LaunchAgents/org.my.custom.plist
```

You can then (re)start the service using

```
launchctl kickstart -k gui/<UID>/org.my.custom
```

Here `<UID>` is the user's UID which can be found with `id -u <username>`.